# How to get RSA encryption progress for multiple files in a directory

Tags: c#, encryption, rsa

I want to encrypt, for example, a bunch of files in my "ToEncrypt" **folder**, how would I get the **real-time encryption progress** of the total files to encrypt? (or the crypted files progress, in case the first option is a bad idea for some reason).

This is how i encrypt data:

```cs
static public byte[] Encryption(byte[] Data, RSAParameters RSAKey, bool DoOAEPPadding)
{
    try
    {
       byte[] encryptedData;
       using (RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
       {
          RSA.ImportParameters(RSAKey); encryptedData = RSA.Encrypt(Data, DoOAEPPadding);
       } return encryptedData;
    }
    catch (CryptographicException e)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
       return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Encrypt with RSA? It will be slow and unnecessary overhead due to the padding. Use AES-GCM instead.

Comment: Just a note - depending on your RSA key size there are just some hundred bytes in the file you can encrypt. As already commented by @kelalaka I recommend AES GCM as well. How do you want to "measure" the progress - the number of files you have encrypted or the total sum of file sizes ? Btw - that has nothing to do with encryption but with your file management.

Comment: Encrypt the files with AES-GCM and encrypt the AES key with RSA. That's called hybrid encryption. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem